# Having AutoMapper to inject dependencies using an IoC Container when needed

Tags: inversion-of-control, unity-container, automapper, constructor-injection

I have tried almost everything, but I cannot get AutoMapper to map A => B **when B doesn't have a parameterless constructor**.

I'm using Unity and all the dependencies are registered conveniently but, how do I say to AutoMapper "hey, if the target instance needs some dependency in the constructor, ask Unity to build it, and do the mapping later.

I've tried with

```
 Mapper.Initialize(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.ConstructServicesUsing(container.Resolve);
            configuration.CreateMap<Person, PersonViewModel>();
        });
```

But it doesn't work :(

EDIT: In fact, I lied a bit. I'm not using Unity. I'm using [Grace](https://github.com/ipjohnson/Grace), but didn't want to come up with a relatively unknown container asking about advances topics :)

I've solved the problem and it works as smooth as silk. The exact code is like this. Keep in mind that I'm using the Grace IoC Container (which I eagerly recommend).

```
Bootstrapper.Instance.Configure(new CompositionRoot());

        Mapper.Configuration.ConstructServicesUsing(type => Bootstrapper.Instance.Container.Locate(type));
        Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonViewModel>()
            .ConstructUsingServiceLocator();
```

Comment: Please do not misdirect the community with questions such as this. Not only the respondent won't be able to give you the correct answer since you're asking the question about an irrelevant subject while the question's phrased and tagged as if it was about Unity, but also this will leave the question quite useless for users who'll be searching StackOverflow for the remainder of this sites life.
There simply is no shame in asking the correct question about Grace instead of asking a misleading question about Unity... If only, it's vice versa..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
configuration.CreateMap<Person, PersonViewModel>()
    .ConstructUsingServiceLocator();
```

Do this for each mapping that should be created by your service locator.