# MVC Ninject into Automapper Profile

Tags: ninject, automapper, ninject.web.mvc

I'm trying to inject my dependencies into an automapper profile; the profile is like so;

```
public class UserProfile : Profile
{
    private IIdentityService _identity;

    public UserProfile(IIdentityService identity)
    {
        _identity = identity;
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserViewModel>();

        Mapper.CreateMap<List<User>, UsersViewModel>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Users, o => o.MapFrom(s => s))
            .ForMember(d => d.Domains, o => GetDomains());
    }

    public List<string> GetDomains()
    {
        return _identity.AvailableDomains();
    }
}
```

Several articles suggest using code like so;

```
        kernel.Bind<IMappingEngine>().ToMethod(ctx => Mapper.Engine);
```

I've tried adding this in NinjectWebCommon (both in CreateKernel and RegisterServices), but i'm still getting runtime errors as AutoMapper can't resolve without a default (empty) constructor. I'm guessing the issue is with the Ninject side of things (my implementation of it that is).

Comment: might this be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104798/having-automapper-to-inject-dependencies-using-an-ioc-container-when-needed ?

Comment: Using the accepted answer there, because I'm using profiles .ServiceLocator won't really help as the constructor is still called prior to this.

Comment: Think the differences are that i'm trying to use profiles (and that the IoC container is different).

Comment: Did you get it working? If there was anything special you had to configure (because of profiles), could you document it (answer your own question).